# Memory overusage in Play! Framework method call

Tags: memory, controller, playframework

In one of my Controllers, I have multiple URLs that will ultimately render in the same way.  For example, this method scans the network on which the server resides, caches a String representation of each connected device and each device listening on a specific port, and then sends that information to another method to render:

```
public static void networkScan(String networkTarget, String port)
{
    //These two lists will never have more than 256 total entries
    List<InetSocketAddress> listeningDevices;
    Map<String, String> allDevices;

    ...Logic for discovering network devices...

    //Store the results in a cache, for history preservation in the browser
    Cache.set(session.getId() + "listeningDevices", listeningDevices);
    Cache.set(session.getId() + "allDevices", allDevices);
    showScan(listeningDevices, allDevices);
}

public static void showScan(List<InetSocketAddress> listeningDevices, Map<String, String> allDevices)
{
    render(listeningDevices, allDevices);
}

public static void getCachedScan()
{
    List<InetSocketAddress> listeningDevices = (List<InetSocketAddress>)Cache.get(session.getId() + "listeningDevices");
    Map<String, String> allDevices = (Map<String, String>)Cache.get(session.getId() + "allDevices");
    if(listeningDevices == null)
        listeningDevices = new ArrayList<InetSocketAddress>();
    if(allDevices == null)
        allDevices = new TreeMap<String, String>();

    renderScan(listeningDevices, allDevices);
}
```

Doing it this way results in Play doing some weird array copying that ends up taking infinite memory.  If I were to change my call of `showScan()` to simply `render()` and create a view with the name `networkScan.html`, it all works just fine, no memory bugs.

I have several other methods that also use showScan, based on different caching settings.  I don't want lots of views that are all essentially copies of each other, so I'm trying to go through just one method with one corresponding view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that calling an action method creates a redirect event, which resulted in all sorts of copying objects into URLs.  I still don't understand how that mushroomed into using over a gigabyte of memory for a collection of Strings that rarely numbered above 100, and never above 256, but I found a way of avoiding the redirect event.

As I was directed to do in an [answer](http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/a44184382a370d52) on Google Groups, I made use of the `@Util` interceptor on the showScan method:

```
@Util
public static void showScan(List<InetSocketAddress> listeningDevices, Map<String, String> allDevices)
{
    renderTemplate("Admin/showScan.html", listeningDevices, allDevices);
}
```

Marking a method with `@Util` unfortunately makes it use the template of the calling method, but the call to `renderTemplate()` allows me to use a single template that I specify.

Answer (score 2):

This won't work:

```
   showScan(listeningDevices, allDevices);
}

public static void showScan(List<InetSocketAddress> listeningDevices, Map<String, String> allDevices)
{
```

as play will serialize listeningDevices + allDevices to Strings and tries to build a url out of it.

either directly render the results in networkScan() or store the contents in the cache under a specific key
like you already do and then do something like

```
public static void networkScan(String networkTarget, String port)
{
    //These two lists will never have more than 256 total entries
    List<InetSocketAddress> listeningDevices;
    Map<String, String> allDevices;



       ...Logic for discovering network devices...

        //Store the results in a cache, for history preservation in the browser
        Cache.set(session.getId() + "listeningDevices", listeningDevices);
        Cache.set(session.getId() + "allDevices", allDevices);
        showScan(session.getId());
    }

    public static void showScan(String sessionId)
    {
    List<InetSocketAddress> listeningDevices = Cache.get(sessionId + "listeningDevices");
    Map<String, String> allDevices = Cache.get(sessionId + "allDevices");
        render(listeningDevices, allDevices);
    }
```

Comment: I think your answer works, but I ended up going with a different solution.  The `@Util` interceptor prevents a redirect event when calling an action method.  This will cover all my bases, no matter if I want to utilize the cache or not.  It's not well-documented, but I got the answer when I asked on the Google group: http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/a44184382a370d52